# Hide datagridview column but still access it value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

The below code is using the column that i want to be not visible which is [0]

```
LoadData();
MessageBox.Show(p.AddNew());
dgpay.DataSource = p.AllData();
p.Move2Last();
ShowData();
for (int i = 0; i < dgpay.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (!dgpay.Rows[i].IsNewRow)
    {
        if (dgpay[0, i].Value.ToString() == txtpaymentid.Text)
        {
            dgpay.CurrentCell = dgpay.Rows[i].Cells[0];
            dgpay.Rows[i].Selected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            dgpay.Rows[i].Selected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

When i tried to make `dgpay.Columns[0].Visible = false` the above code wont run probably.

How can i hide the column without affecting the code.

Comment: What's your goal? You hide the first column but then you tried to set current cell to a cell of first column.

Comment: Columns are fix or you are creating it in runtime?

Comment: yes Reza Aghaei

Comment: Kishan Sojitra created in run time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hide the first column but then you tried to set current cell to a cell of first column.  When you set current cell to an invisible cell you will receive an `InvalidOperationException`:

> Current cell cannot be set to an invisible cell.

Just set the current cell using a visible column index, for example:

```
dgpay.CurrentCell = dgpay.Rows[i].Cells[1]; // I supposed Columns[1].Visible is true
```